# How to perform nested query on two different conditions in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, associations

Here's my case.

I'm building a system in which you have users (consider them admins) that create employees and a performance report is created for every employee. The users can only view employees that were created by users from the same company. However, another company can create a report for an employee from a different company using a search field. Once a report is created for that employee, then they can view that employee within the employees list, if the report is not there, they wouldn't have seen it within that list.

***Note: The model names are changed but have same characteristics***

I'm trying to have an endpoint which returns all employees based on either of these two scenarios:

1. Return all employees created by the user which their company belong to the same company as the user initiating the request.
2. Return all employees that (if they don't belong to the same company as the user who created the employee) have a report associated to them and the report was created by a user from the same company as the user initiating the request.

Here's a brief ERD that explains the relationship between the models:

[image]

Here's the code which uses nested joins:

```
async function getAll(company) {
  
  return await Employee.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          '$User.company$': { [Op.eq]: company }
        },
        {
          '$Report.User.company$': { [Op.eq]: company }
        }
      ]
    },
    include: [
      {
        attributes: [],
        model: User.scope('withoutPassword'),
      },
      {
        attributes: [],
        model: Report,
        include: {
          attributes: [],
          model: User.scope('withoutPassword'),
        }
      }
    ]
  })
    .then(employees => {
      return employees
    });
}
```